# Generating a dataframe based off the diff between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames that look like this

```
Df1 
City    Code    ColA    Col..Z
LA      LAA  
LA      LAB
LA      LAC


Df2 
Code    ColA    Col..Z
LA      LAA 
NY      NYA
CH      CH1
```

What I'm trying to do have the result of

```
df3 
Code ColA   Col..Z
NY  NYA
CH  CH1
```

Normally I would loop through each row in df2 and say:

Df3 = If df2.row['Code'] in df1 then drop it.

But I want to find a pythonic pandas way to do it instead of looping through the dataframe. I was looking at examples using joins or merging but I cant seem to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *Df3 = If df2.row['Code'] in df1 then drop it.* translates to

```
df3 = df2[~df2['Code'].isin(df1['City'] ]
```

Comment: Ended up using this . It worked well. I did a minor syntax fix: `df3 = df2[~df2['Code'].isin(df1['Code'] )]`

Answer (score 1):

To keep only the different items in `df2` based on the `code` column, you can do something like this, using `drop_duplicates` :

```py
df2[df2.code.isin(
    # the different values in df2's 'code' column
    pd.concat([df1.code, df2.code]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [pandas `compare` df method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html#pandas.DataFrame.compare) which might be relevant?:

```py
df1 = pd.read_clipboard()
df1
```

[image: df1]

```py
df2 = pd.read_clipboard()
df2
```

[image: df2]

```py
df1.compare(df2).drop('self', axis=1, level=1).droplevel(1, axis=1)
```

[image: df compare diff]

(And I'm making an assumption you had a typo in your dataframes with the City col missing from df2?)